# DNS, SPF Web Form, Mail not arriving

Tags: php, g-suite, spf

I need to be able to receive emails from my php webform on my website, I use Google Apps for the mail recipient and my website is hosted with Godaddy. I receive email from other places and I have looked and I think the problem is that the web sever thinks they are 'local' messages. In addition to this I also want to allow a site called bookerville to send messages from my site on my behalf. They provided me with the follow SPF code...

```
v=spf1 include:bookerville.com ?all
```

Some one set up the current SPF record which seems to be invalid which is (i don't think the ip4 bit is correct as I beleive it needs the sever ip address after it? Also I read on another thread that the ip4 bit isn't required???:

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:v=spf1 include:bookerville.com ?all include:secureserver.net ~all
```

I had a look around the web and on here and this seems to be the closest solution although I don't know much about Mx and SPF records so feeling out of my depth.

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com a a:abc.example.org a:xyz.example.org -all
```

. This says, include Google's SPF record (which will allow all their mail servers to send mail on behalf of your domain), and allow anything in this domain which has an A record, and specifically allow 2 other hosts by verifying their A records. Fail everything else.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441924/setup-spf-record-to-allow-sending-email-from-google-apps-and-bluehost/11442044#11442044

Lets say my website is www.example.com. Can someone provide me with a suitable SPF text to include the bookerville code (ABOVE) and also any code required for google and which will allow for php form mail to come through??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:bookerville.com a -all
```

Breakdown:

- include:_spf.google.com: Parse the SPF record for _spf.google.com as example.com's own
- include:bookerville.com: Parse the SPF record for bookersville.com as example.com's own
- a: The IP address example.com resolves to (its A record in DNS thus) is permitted to send
- -all: All other senders are considered illegitimate

This will only work correctly under the following conditions:

- There's a single A record for example.com
- When you send e-mail via the PHP form, the e-mail is sent from the IP address that the A record of example.com resolves to.

Example 1:

example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1

Webserver sends e-mail with source IP 192.0.2.1 => OK

Example 2:

example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1

Webserver send e-mail with source IP 192.0.2.88 => NOT OK

Tools you can use:

- Check SPF record online: http://tools.bevhost.com/spf/
- SPF syntax (I highly recommend reading through this): http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax
- SPF record wizard: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Comment: Thanks for that, its a great help. Will this solve the problem with the php form sending 'local' email, (as it's local the godaddy server manages it locally, rather than sending to google? - Or is that a seperate issue?)

Comment: It'll possibly solve it, but to be sure you'll have to ask GoDaddy, as they know which IP address the e-mail from your PHP form will originate from.